# Put img tag inside the top right corner of a div

Tags: css, image, position

I'd like to put a `<a href="..."><img /></a>` tag (linked image) in the top right corner of an existing div.

I've found a way to put an image as the background with no-repeat, but then, I cannot link the image. What CSS shall I use?

This is what I do have now:

```
<div id="footer">
  some multi-line commercial text content
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#footer
    {
        line-height:18px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-230px;
        left:0;
        width:280px;
    }

#footer span
    {
        font-size:16px;
        display:block;
    }
```

The icon I want to put there and link is 43x38 size. The footer div is 280x186 size (in the google chrome webmaster stuff).

Comment: Can you please paste your existing code so we can see how the current visuals look like?

Comment: @tutipute ok - here you go!

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz I cannot see any `img` in your code

Comment: @user1479606 I want to put the `<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>` tag somewhere (with appropriate CSS) so that it is displayed in the top right corner. It can be inside the div, outside the div, well, I don't know - this is what I ask for ;)

Comment: I'm still not sure what are the limitations, please check out this JSFiddle and relate. http://jsfiddle.net/8V5Zm/1/ (dimensions are a bit different)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the container position:relative

Make the image position:absolute;right:0px;

Comment: position: relative is not neccessary. absolute will work also.

Comment: @Vanco Very Simplified answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
<div class="ImageDiv">
    <a href="#" class="hiddenlink"></a>
</div>

.ImageDiv {
    background-image: url(someurl);
    position: relative; //parent div has to be relative position for absolute position children to stay in it.
}
.hiddenlink {
    The way you want to do.
}
```